# Hecke $L$-function of cusp form is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f=\sum a(n)q^n\in S_k(N,\chi)$ be a cusp form of integral weight. Can someone give me the proof of the fact that : the Hecke $L$-function $L(f,s)=\sum\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$ is entire.

I searched in Koblitz's book "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular forms" and  Diamond's book "A First Course in Modular forms" but I cannot find anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is very straightforward. I'll let you fill in the details.

As $f$ is cuspidal, you have that $f(iy) \to 0$ super-polynomially fast as $y \to \infty$. Consider the integral function
$$ I(s) = \int_0^\infty f(iy) y^s \frac{dy}{y}.$$
The super-decay of $f(iy)$ guarantees convergence for every $s$, and this is clearly an analytic function in $s$. For $s$ with $\text{Re} s$ large enough, we may substitute the Fourier expansion to recognize
$$ I(s) = \int_0^\infty \sum a(n) e^{-2\pi ny} y^s \frac{dy}{y}.$$
As
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi n y} y^s \frac{dy}{y} = (2\pi n)^{-s} \Gamma(s),$$
we see that
$$ I(s) = L(s,f) \Gamma(s) (2\pi)^{-s}.$$
So $L(s)$ is necessarily entire, and $I(s)$ is really the completed $L$-function $\Lambda(s)$.

Futher, one can prove the functional equation by using the modularity condition satisfied by $f(iy)$ under the action of the distinguished matrix $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} & -1 \\ N& \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer

Comment: I don't buy this argument: what about the convergence of the integral towards $y = 0$? The usual way of setting up this argument in the literature is to use the action of $\begin{pmatrix} &-1\\N\end{pmatrix}$ along the way, transforming it into a sum of two integrals over $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}, \infty)$ which do indeed obviously define entire functions of $s$. The standard references are Diamond + Shurman or Miyake.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, Thanks Mr Loeffler,  can you give me the page where I can find it on Diamond or Miyake ?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, I want I also see the proof in the Half-integra case, can suggest me exactly where I can find it ?

Comment: Diamond & Shurman theorem 5.10.2, Miyake corollary 4.3.7. Neither treat the half-integral case, but you should be able to work it out for yourself based on those references.